# Function returns duplicate records incorrectly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried creating an event listener for each filter i have on my webpage, and I want to record which one was changed. While my code does track it correctly, it returns duplicate records, instead of one single entry. I suspect it is because I might not be unregistering the filter handler functions correctly, but I am a complete rookie here.

```
<script>

        window.onload = tableau.extensions.initializeAsync().then(() => {
            let dashboard = tableau.extensions.dashboardContent.dashboard;
            let dashboardName 
            let worksheetNames = []
            let filterName = []
            let unregisterFilterHandlerFunctions = []

            dashboardName = dashboard.name
            document.getElementById("dashboardName").innerHTML=dashboardName; 

            function getDateTimestamp(){
                var today = new Date();
                var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
                var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
                var dateTime = date+' '+time;
                return dateTime;
            }

            function unregisterFilterHandlers() {
                unregisterFilterHandlerFunctions.forEach(function (unregisterFilterHandlerFunction) {
                    unregisterFilterHandlerFunctions();
                });
            }

            function registerFilterHandlers() {
                dashboard.worksheets.forEach(function (worksheet) {
                    let unregisterHandlerFunction = worksheet.addEventListener(tableau.TableauEventType.FilterChanged,filterChangeHandler);
                    unregisterFilterHandlerFunctions.push(unregisterHandlerFunction);
                });
            }

            function filterChangeHandler(filterEvent){
                const details = {
                    method: 'POST'
                };
                fetch(`https://serverurl/${filterEvent.fieldName}/Filter/${getDateTimestamp()}/${dashboardName}`, details).then((res) => {console.log(res);});
                unregisterFilterHandlers();
                registerFilterHandlers();
            }
          
            registerFilterHandlers();
</script>
```

And here is my actual app in nodeJS.

```
const app = require('express')();
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  var readStream = fs.createReadStream('index.html','utf8');
  readStream.pipe(res);
});

app.post('/:fieldName/:flag/:time/:dashboard', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('POST message received', req.params);
    if (req.params && req.params.fieldName) {
        await fs.appendFileSync('./changeLog.csv', `${req.params.fieldName},${req.params.flag},${req.params.time},${req.params.dashboard}\n`);
    }
});
```

Finally, this is the output i get. While I only made one filter change on the front end, it renders 6 different messages pointing to the same filter.

[image]

Comment: The standard DOM `.addEventListener` returns `undefined`, so it's possible `let unregisterHandlerFunction` is just `undefined` - can you try logging it out and check if it contains a value? If that's the case, I'd expect that you'd see one additional POST message each time it's triggered, since it's never unregistered (so 1 message on first submit, then 2, then 3, and so on).

Comment: Here is the output I got: 
function () {return_this.removeEventListener(handler);}

After running this: 
let unregisterHandlerFunction = worksheet.addEventListener(tableau.TableauEventType.FilterChanged,filterChangeHandler);     document.getElementById("handler").innerHTML=unregisterHandlerFunction

Comment: Hmm, that's not the issue then. Perhaps it's firing the `FilterChanged` event multiple times, maybe once per worksheet? I would add `console.log(filterEvent)` as the first line of `filterChangeHandler` and see if each copy of the event appears different in any way (maybe it has a worksheet ID you can use to differentiate?).

Comment: You were right with your suspicion. While a filter is created on one specific worksheet, it can be applied to impact multiple worksheets. Looking at the console, I see one worksheet name for every sheet that it impacts on the calls that are returned. But because i need to add the listener against the worksheet object, I don't know how to avoid the current behavior.

Comment: If you only want to notify the server of filter changes to the current worksheet, you can get the current worksheet with `workbook.getActiveSheet()` and then in `filterChangeHandler` ignore events for other worksheets, something like `const activeSheet = workbook.getActiveSheet(); if (event.worksheet.name !== activeSheet.name) return;` (I'm not familiar with the API, you may need to tweak names slightly).

Comment: @superhawk610 thank you so much for your patience so far but i fear i may have hit a dead end. in Tableau, the application i am building this on, a dashboard can have one or many worksheets. so in a dashboard, there isn't an 'Active Sheet' per say. If I define one as the active when the application initially loads, i may accidentally pick one that doesn't have all elements. Worksheet A may have 10 filters while Worksheet B has 20. If i set A as active, but click on a filter that is only present on B, I would never get a response. At least if I am understanding this approach correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
function registerFilterHandlers() {
    dashboard.worksheets.forEach(function (worksheet) {
        worksheet.addEventListener(tableau.TableauEventType.FilterChanged, filterChangeHandler);
        unregisterFilterHandlerFunctions.push(
          () => worksheet.removeEventListener(tableau.TableauEventType.FilterChanged, filterChangeHandler)
        );
    });
}
```

https://help.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_concepts_events.htm

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I replaced my function with what you provided here but I am still getting the same results. Should I remove the unregisterFilterHandlers() function or was the only change supposed to be the one you pasted above?